# How can I displayed captured input in typo3?

Tags: content-management-system, typo3, web-applications

I create a form wherein the user enters some values but I now need to retrieve those values to display in a table. I'm unsure about how to achieve this. I'm working with the intro package and new to the system. I've read some tutorials but nothing about achieving this.

Edit: I should mention that I need to persist these values in a database first before attempting to display it.

Comment: Your question basically consists of one sentence. That's way too little information to give you an answer to your specific problem. However, I've given you at least a general answer.

Comment: How Your form was exactly created ?

Comment: @FedirI created the form in the backend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, the easiest way is to use [Powermail](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/powermail/current/) extension, which handles many cases.

You could save the submitted data in dB and show it after with Your extension, or TypoScript configuration.

Comment: Thanks. This sounds like exactly what I need to get started with testing.